# How appstore, test applications which communicate with local servers

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am new in iphone development. I am developing an application, which is targeted to the costumers of a shopping mall. The application installed in the customers iPhone, wil communicate with a server in the mall(via wifi) and update him/her with various offers in the mall. 
I am in the final stages of development and planning to submit the application for AppStore approval, once I complete dev. and testing.

I understand that, AppStore will test the application, when we submit it for approval. 
In many occasions the application communicates with the local server to get data from it. 
I would like to know, how they will test my application, without running the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit your application to Appstore there's a place in forms where you can give account info for testing:

> **Demo Account - Full Access** Please
>   provide us with the details of any
>   test accounts that we can use for
>   testing your application. This can
>   include usernames, passwords, access
>   codes, etc.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response. 
Does this mean, I need to submit my server application along with the mobile app?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice at once that your server is not available online... I'm a little help here then :( 
You can make server available through web at least during test period or describe this situation directly to apple for them to decide (or ask Apple support). 
Anyway it's interesting situation, hope to here about the solution you'll come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to expose your web services to the outside. It sounds like you want to advertise specials for the stores while people are in the mall... Well, if I download the app, wouldn't I want to sometimes view the specials when I'm at home? or on the way to the mall?

It seems to me that you're crippling your app from the start if you don't allow people to use it outside of your wifi network.

If your authentication is good enough, it shouldn't be a problem to launch your server-side stuff on a live web server somewhere and point your app at that.